# How to extract database from WhereIsIt catalog software and save that database as an excel or text file?

Tags: database, extract, save-as, self-extracting

can anyone knows how to extract database from WhereIsIt catalog software and save that database as an excel or text file?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export as `*.xls`  or `*.csv` file formats.

##### Report Generator Wizard

The built-in **"Report Generator Wizard"** to export the data in file formats including:
|   ASCII    |   **MS Excel**    |   Rich Text (RTF)    |   HTML    |   **Comma Separated (CSV)**    |   Symbolic Link Text (SYLK)    |   SQL Script    |   XML    |

##### Steps

1. Click the <kbd>Main</kbd> button, then point to <kbd>Report Generator</kbd>, and click on <kbd>Report Generator Wizard</kbd>
   [image]
2. Click <kbd>Next</kbd> to move on from the **"Report Generator Wizard"** description dialog box
   [image]
3. Choose an option from the **"Report Generator Wizard"** dialog box and click <kbd>Next</kbd>
   [image]
4. Customize options based on choice in previous step and click click <kbd>Finish</kbd>
   [image]
5. Select file format from the **"Export"** drop-menu in the **"Report Destination"** section of the **"Report Generator"** dialog box
   [image]